# Determine if a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-entery is given by 
$$A_{ij}=\sum_{p=1}^nS_{pi}S_{pj}+\sum_{p,q=1}^n|S_{pq}|^2\delta_{ij}.$$
I wonder if $A$ is positive definite. I try to calculate $v^TAv$ as follows: 
$$v^TAv=\sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}v_iv_j=\sum_{i,j,p=1}^nS_{pi}S_{pj}v_iv_j+
\sum_{i,p,q=1}^n|S_{pq}|^2v_i^2.$$

Comment: What is $S$? Is it just another matrix?

Comment: Yes. Or just think $S_{ij}$ as some set of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_{ij} = (S e_i)^T S e_j + t e_i^T e_j = e_i^T (S^T S + tI)e_j$, where
$t = \sum_{p,q=1}^n|S_{pq}|^2$.

Hence $A = S^TS+tI$ which is positive definite **iff** $S \neq 0$.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!